# Laravel - Send Mail in Future based on condition

Tags: laravel, email, cron, queue, beanstalkd

I want to send emails to various users based on the schedules they have set.

I read about [beanstalkd](https://laracasts.com/lessons/beanstalkd-queues-with-laravel), [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) and [Delayed Message Queueing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail) and for now it looks like fitting in:

```
$when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($minutes); // i can calculate minutes at this moment
\Mail::to($user)->later($when, new \App\Mail\TestMail);
```

But i'm not quite sure on few things:

1. User can cancel a future schedule. In that case how do i cancel an email that's suppose to send in future. Can i set condition somewhere that gets checked before sending the actual email? Tried `return false` on `handle` method of `\App\Mail\TestMail` and it started throwing error
2. Am i using the right approach. I also read about [Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) but i don't get how i am going to cancel future emails(if they need to be)

Comment: create a db field in emails table as is_active if its one against an email email should go otherwise if user unsubscribes or stop getting it should be 0 so you can use condition on is_active base..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. Personally I would queue the emails on a schedule rather than adding them to the queue for later.

So you run a scheduled task once a day (or hour, or minute) which runs a query to select which users require an email, then using that result set, you add a job to the queue for each result.

This way, if a user unsubscribes, you don't have to worry about removing already queued jobs.

Laravel offers quite a nice interface for creating scheduled jobs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) which can then be called via a cronjob.